# No-interaction theorem in classical relativistic mechanics

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, poincare-symmetry, integrable-systems

In classical relativistic Hamiltonian mechanics there is a so-called "no-interaction theorem" (see, for example, [this article for a proof](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02749856)). Roughly, it states that if we have an $N$-body mechanical system hamiltonian $H$ in $d>1+1$, such that one can construct boosts/translations/rotations generators obeying Poincare algebra together with $H$ then one can make a canonical transformation of variables $p,q$ such that all the generators assume there free particle form.

There is a certain assumption in the proof of the theorem that I don't understand the meaning of: we assume that "coordinates of the particles $q^a$ transform correctly under the inhomogeneous Lorentz group". This is expressed in terms of 3 relations on Poisson brackets with Poincare generators; the most mysterious one is
$$
[q^a, K] = q^a [q^a, H]
$$
with $K$ being the boost operator. What is the meaning of these conditions? Why it is natural to demand that?

Reason I'm asking is that in the few examples of relativistic $N$-body systems in 2D that I know (Ruusenars-Schneider model in particular) this relations do not hold, although it looks like the relevant variables are precisely particle coordinates. It is stated in their original article [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(86)90097-7) that this is the exact reason why they were able to find a non-trivial $N$-body relativistic system.

Comment: In that paper $a$ labels the particles (1 to n) and their index $i$ labels space dimensions (1 to 3), so (1.2) says $\{q^a_i, K_j\}=q^a_i\{q^a_j, H\}$. But (1.2) contradicts (3.1) in that paper, so I guess we'll never know.

Comment: Well, there're just some typos in that article here and there. Still, this requirement should also make sense in 2d, when space dimension index doesn't matter; if one could at least clarify the meaning of this requirement in this case, which is of particular interest to me, it would be very helpful.

Comment: No idea -- I'm also mystified